# Creating new measures in igraph

Tags: r, social-networking, igraph

I want to create a function for Burt's effective size.
The formula boils down to:

**Effective size = n - 2t/n**

- where t is the number of ties (not counting ties to ego)
- n is the number of people in the network (not counting ego).

I'm not really sure where to start with writing functions within/for igraph.

Let me know if more detail would be helpful...

Thanks.

Comment: Provide a sample graph, and what you've tried so far for calculating the size.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First simulate a basic graph:

```
require(igraph)

alters = 50
ties   = 10
set.seed(12345)
edgelist = rbind(0, 1:alters)
edgelist = cbind(edgelist, replicate(ties, sample(alters, 2)))
g = graph(edgelist, directed=F)

dev.new(width=5, height=5)
plot(g, layout=layout.kamada.kawai)
```

[image]

Then write a simple function to calculate the effective size. (The functions in here that operate on `g` are all nicely documented in the `igraph` manual and in various examples around the net.)

```
EffectiveSize <- function(g, ego=0) {
  n = neighbors(g, ego)
  t = length(E(g)[to(n) & !to(ego)])
  n = length(n)
  n - 2 * t / n
}
```

```
> EffectiveSize(g)
[1] 49.6
```

Comment: Ah. Thank you! Sorry for the redundant/basic question, but I really wasn't sure if I'd have to call/edit in C. I didn't realize I could create normal R functions to work with igraph.

Comment: Yea it's really flexible like that. igraph is a great package too, with these slick ways of indexing/iterating on the vertices and edges. Good luck with your project!